# Oracle SQL Group By Hour for 24 hours

Tags: oracle, hour

I have this query, which works:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(last_date_called,'HH24'), count(*) 
FROM log_table
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(last_date_called,'HH24');
```

But, in some cases there are not 24 hours worth of data.   What I want to do, is always generate 24 rows, and if there is nothing for that hour, return 0.   So, results may look like this:

```
00   10
01   25
02   33
03   0
04   55
05   0
06   23
```

And so on........

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a *row generator* to create all hours in a day, and then outer join it to your "real" table. Something like this (see comments within code):

```
SQL> with
  2  hours as
  3    -- row generator, to create all hours in a day
  4    (select lpad(level - 1, 2, '0') hour
  5     from dual
  6     connect by level <= 24
  7    ),
  8  log_table (last_date_called) as
  9    -- sample data, just to return "something"
 10    (select to_date('08.07.2021 13:32', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
 11     select to_date('16.02.2021 08:20', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual
 12    )
 13  -- final query
 14  select h.hour,
 15         count(l.last_date_called) cnt
 16  from hours h left join log_table l on h.hour = to_char(l.last_date_called, 'hh24')
 17  group by h.hour
 18  order by h.hour;

HO        CNT
-- ----------
00          0
01          0
02          0
03          0
04          0
05          0
06          0
07          0
08          1
09          0
10          0
11          0
12          0
13          1
14          0
15          0
16          0
17          0
18          0
19          0
20          0
21          0
22          0
23          0

24 rows selected.

SQL>
```